# prevent multiple call in appframework touchevents

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, appframework

I'm using Intel Appframework to create android app. Now I'm tryng to bind touchevent but I see that makes a redundant multiple ajax call!

this is my script:

```
$(document).on("doubleTap", ".chatOp a[rel]", function(){
        var nomeSuo = $(this).attr('rel');
        $.post('http://www.mimanchitu.it/appf/include/chat_con.asp', {M_FROM:localStorage.getItem("nameStorage"),M_TO:nomeSuo}, 
    function(oldChat){
        $("#showChat").empty();
        $("#showChat").html(oldChat);
        return $.ui.loadContent("#chat_con")
        });
    })


$(document).on("longTap", ".chatOp a[rel]", function(){
        var nomeSuo = $(this).attr('rel');
        var nomeTuo = localStorage.getItem("nameStorage");
        alert("vuoi eliminare?");
        $.post('http://www.mimanchitu.it/appf/include/chat_delAll.asp', {from:nomeSuo,to:nomeTuo}, function(){
            $("#"+nomeSuo).remove();
            });
    })
```

I use this to bind different event for double Tap or long tap case! But in all two cases make multiple ajax call!

To prevent multiple call in other case I use onclick: in a element....but for touch how I have to do?!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `preventDefault()` as the first statement within your anonymous function? You'll need to pass `event` as the argument:

```
$(document).on("longTap", ".chatOp a[rel]", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   ...
```

Comment: Ill try but never change. My personal solution is to specify a div: for example:
$('#mydiv').on("longTap", ".chatOp a [rel]", ecc...